# Runtime error when building SFML with pure CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml, clion

I am starting a project that uses SFML 2.5.1. I am on Windows, and I'm trying to build using pure CMake. The CMake and compilation steps appear to be working fine, but when I try to run my program in CLion, I get the following error:

`Process finished with exit code -1073741515`

Further, if I find the executable in commandline and attempt to run it there, the program crashes with the following message:

`The code execution cannot proceed because sfml-window-d-2.dll was not found.`

For context, my project has a file main.cpp in its root directory, as well as my CMakeLists.txt file. The root directory also contains the SFML source code as downloaded from the "Source Code" download link at https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/ .

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(sfmltest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_subdirectory(SFML)

include_directories(SFML/include)

add_executable(sfmltest main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(sfmltest sfml-graphics sfml-audio sfml-network sfml-window sfml-system)
```

Here is my main.cpp. It's just a standard SFML "Hello World" application.

```cpp
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Am I missing something in my CMakeLists.txt file?

EDIT 1: I don't want a fix such as copy and pasting dll's. I want to be able to build SFML purely from scratch. This is to make sure my project is portable, cross-platform, easy to set up, and compilable with CMake in CLion (NOT Visual Studio or Code::Blocks).

EDIT 2: Adding `set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS FALSE)` to my CMakeLists.txt file did the trick. My minimal program is now working!

Comment: *The code execution cannot proceed because sfml-window-d-2.dll was not found* -- This has nothing to do with building the application.  Your application, at run time, is looking for this DLL and it can't find it (either in the application directory or on the `PATH`).

Comment: "if you linked to the dynamic version of SFML, don't forget to copy the SFML DLLs (they are in <sfml-install-path/bin>) to the directory where your compiled executable is." from [SFML Docs](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php).

Comment: I get that the error means the dll's are missing, but I'm wondering if there is any way to build SFML from scratch with CMake without copy and pasting dll's or building SFML separately and then linking it. After all, dll's are created in the first place by building SFML. See edit on the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `sfml-window-d-2.dll` is missing. Add the path to the directory containing SFML DLLs to the Code::Block dynamic library search path (if there is such a thing in C::B) or add it to the PATH environment variable or simply copy those libraries to the folder containing the Executable. You can add a post build step that will copy these libraries.

Edit:
I can't comment because of my low reputation.

You can build SFML static libraries to avoid copying dlls. You must disable `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` option in CMake.

Comment: Never said I was using Code::Blocks. I am aiming to use pure CMake. See the edit on the OP.

Comment: Oh, sorry.. I had to make a mistake when I was looking for SFML (most of the tutorials are in C::B). See my edit. It should solve your problem.

Comment: Wow, adding `set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS FALSE)` to my CMakeLists.txt file actually did the trick. Thank you so much!